# Help/Advice with wooden floor repairs

Tags: repair, flooring, hardwood-floor

I'm looking for help with some problems I'm having with my wood flooring. In short, some wood planks need to be replaced, but I can't find where to buy more.

- **Problem 1**: a delivery company scratched the floor pretty badly in some areas. They literally tilted a fridge and dragged it across the floor. smh
- **Problem 2**: two planks raised up creating a tripping hazard. There doesn't seem to be water underneath, but it's right in front of the fridge (has a water dispenser).

Photos: https://imgur.com/a/dit2hcD

**Question:**

Are there other ways to fix these 2 problems other than replacing the planks? E.g. filler, polish, glue the raised planks and weigh them down, something else?

I found a box with 3 planks in it in our garage, but I'm not sure where to find replacements, or where the previous owners bought them.
It has the following information printed on it:

> ECO FOREST
>
> HDF Engineered Handscraped Strand Woven Bamboo Flooring
>
> Item Desc: BAM 3/8X5 1/8 ENG ST LK HS MD BRN
>
> Sku No.: 100039866
>
> UPC No.: 888369023317

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic, so before it is closed, you could remove point 1.  And just ask what your options are.  Then someone is allowed to give you recommendations.

Comment: @RohitGupta Thanks. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on internet search, it appears those can be glued or floated.  Do you know how yours was installed?  It looks like Eco Forest is a brand carried by Floor & Decor.  I have no clue if your particular style and color is still available—you could contact them with the info you have.

As to the gouges, you have two choices—easy and hard.  The easy button is to buy a furniture marker kit and use the closest color to "paint" the gouges (maybe even blend a couple colors).  The hard button is to replace the bad panels, if your 3 remaining is sufficient.  (The hard button getss even harder if it's glued and not floating).

For the lifting panels, the click-lock function may have failed—or not.  Try putting down a towel to protect the surface, lay a 2x4 along the lifted panels, and using a rubber mallet to whack the panels back into "lock."  If that pushes the panels down far enough, and if the floor is glued, you may consider using some finish nails/brads to lock the lifted panels down, because they'll probably lift again.  Use some furniture crayons to cover the nails.